# Passing parameters to functions outside prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm developing with Node.JS, and I have these functions written in JavaScript:

```
MySqlBl.prototype.getUser = function (email, onGetUserCompleted, onGetUserError) {
    this.execQuery("CALL spGetUser('" + email + "')", onGetUserError, onDone);

    function onDone(rows) {        
        if (typeof rows[0][0] != 'undefined') {
            var row = rows[0][0];           
                console.log('1: ', row.First_Name);
                console.log('2: ', row.Last_Name);
            getUserObject(row.User_ID, row.Email, row.First_Name, row.Last_Name);
        }
    }
};

function getUserObject(userID, email, firstName, lastName) {
   console.log('3: ' + firstName);
   console.log('4: ' + lastName);
}
```

The output i'm getting is:

```
1: Lien
2: Dang
3: undefined
4: undefined
```

Why I can't send the rows values correctly ?

Comment: as I've written: yes. I can.

Comment: Whats that fifth parameter you're passing?

Comment: @tymeJV it's a mistake.. I've edited it.

Comment: What kind of host object is `row`? Does it work if you're removing the direct log calls (1, 2) after the `getUserObject` call? Do you need those other parameters, is the behaviour different if you omit them?

Comment: Safe to assume that you can't log the other 2 variables that are being passed, correct?

Comment: `"CALL spGetUser('" + email + "')"` looks like an SQL injection hazard.

Comment: What do u get when you log `arguments` in the second function?

Comment: @tymeJV I can log them.. but what is the difference ? those are undefined too

Comment: @Bergi that is server side code.

Comment: there's no reason. Try to reproduce it with a testable code without external lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a scope problem.
If you use another var like this :

```
function onDone(rows) {        
    if (typeof rows[0][0] != 'undefined') {
        var row = rows[0][0];           
            console.log('1: ', row.First_Name);
            console.log('2: ', row.Last_Name);
        var first = row.First_Name, last = row.Last_Name;
        getUserObject(row.User_ID, row.Email,first, last);
    }
}
```

Does that work ? (even if it's working, that's not an answer, better keep looking).